# How I make phpunit auth tests for laravel/passport?

Tags: laravel, phpunit

I make backend API with laravel 9 (based on laravel/passport 10.3) and
I init app with command :

php artisan   passport:install
which generates personal access client and client secret code

I use these codes in login request and recieve Bearer Token, which is used in all datas raeding/updating data with request.

Now I make phpunit tests for these requests and wonder in which wat these register/login requests must be tested as
usuallyin tests controllers I use

```
$this->actingAs($user, 'api');
```

Where $user is created with factory...
How that can be implemented ?  Please link to example...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can use :

```
Passport::actingAs($user)
```

and usually we don't test third party code, so don't bother testing passport authentication routes, it's already well tested

but if you really want to do that, you can for example with `$this->postJson`

```
$this->postJson('api/oauth/token', [
            'username'      => 'username',
            'password'      => Str::random(),
            'client_id'     => 'client_id',
            'client_secret' => 'secret',
            'grant_type'    => 'password',
            'scope'         => '*',
])->assertStatus(400)->assertJson([
            'error' => 'invalid_grant',
        ]);
```

Comment: Oh, I mean different. I need to make tests for MY APP register/login requests, when new user is created and logged into the app using oauth/token. I mean I need somehow to to use this oauth/token.

Comment: Well you can test register too, use postJson to send the data to your register routes, and then try to login using oauth with those credentials

Comment: But both register/login requests must have Bearer Token parameter.
In postman I read it from oauth/token url and keep in global params.
How to set/fake Token parameter in register/login requests ?

Comment: well this does not make sense to me, if you are not registered, you cant have a bearer token

Comment: I have a similar problem, I am trying to test my simplest get request in laravel, with passport, but I get "unauthenticated" error in unit test. I have no idea how to make this pass, and I am not willing to put a token into my code anywhere. If you have an example, I'd be happy. It seems I can only test my routes with postman and am not able to write unit tests for a crud backend app?

Comment: @Dgloria use `$this->actingAs()` function in your test setUp function, and pass the user you want to be logged into. Usually users are created using a factory : `$this->user = factory(User::class)->create();` and then `$this->actingAs($this->user);`. You will need to give that user the permissions/roles it needs to perform your tests, if applicable.

Comment: Hi, what is factory? Been looking for it in the docs but could only find old versions. Also haven't found actingAs in the docs for L9 or L10

Comment: @Dgloria yes the syntax changed sorry, now it's `User::factory()->create()` see https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-factories . And `actingAs` is a helper from laravel see https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/http-tests#session-and-authentication

Comment: Also passport has it's own `actingAs`, `Passport::actingAs`, depending on your setup you might want to use that instead

Comment: Hi, thank you, this worked: ```$this->withoutExceptionHandling();

        Passport::actingAs(
            User::factory()->create()
        );

        $response = $this->get('/api/mydata');
        $response->assertStatus(200);```